# Autoplay HTML5 video after it loads

Tags: html, video, gif, autoplay

I want to autoplay an HTML5 video only after it loads. I would also like to have a progress bar (GIF or CSS) while it loads. Any help?

Comment: I'm using video.js and i love it ... very easy to implement int and has all these capabilities. I highly recommend it!

Comment: Any details how to use it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2** Hey so this answer is a specific work around for this scenario (only a 12sec. video for a slow connection wanting to be played back smoothly) nonetheless this should fill your needs:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   _V_("example_video_1").ready(function(){
      var myPlayer = this;
      myPlayer.on("progress", out_started);
  });
});

function out_started(){
  myPlayer =this;
  var myTextArea = document.getElementById('buffered');
  bufferedTimeRange=myPlayer.buffered();
  if ( (bufferedTimeRange.start(0)==0 ) && ( bufferedTimeRange.end(0) -  bufferedTimeRange.start(0) > 10 ) ){
       myPlayer.play();
  }

}
```

So some things, `bufferedTimeRange` can be more then one single rnge of time (but with only 12 sec. of video odds are only one as docs say only 1 ussualy ) .. but not guaranteed . None the less here's a link demoing it http://ec2-23-20-36-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com/video-js.html Hopeully this helps! also if 10 second of buffered video is not enough  you can change the `10` to a `12` in the if statement

**Original Answer**
I am not sure why you would want to do this ... but video.js does make it possible

if you have a video element called `example_video_1` you can write a javscript that look's like this (not this is if you choose to use video.js which again I recomend set up is easy see http://www.videojs.com/ for an example and get started to actually set it up)

```
VideoJS("example_video_1").ready(function(){

    var myPlayer = this;

    var howMuchIsDownloaded = myPlayer.bufferedPercent();
    if(howMuchIsDownloaded == 1){
    myPlayer.play();  //start playing the video 
    }else{
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }
 });
```

**Update** it appears the API call layed out above is presently broken for Video.js (bug has been reported) Here is an example to tell when a video has finished being buffered if your video tag id is `"example_video_1"`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   _V_("example_video_1").ready(function(){
    var myPlayer = this; 
    myPlayer.on("loadedalldata", Done_download);

  });
});

function Done_download(){
   myPlayer =this;
   var myTextArea = document.getElementById('buffered');
   alert("The video has  been fully buffered ");
    myPlayer.off("loadedalldata", Done_download);
 }
```

**Note** there seem's to be an internal mechanism in Video.js that will not allow an entire video stream to be buffered before playback has reached with a certain range of the video (at least with an .mp4 source)
@DONSA you can check out this strange behavior here [video-js sample page](http://ec2-23-20-36-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com/video-js.html) ... ill keep it up for a couple day's on my test server

Comment: I use this @brendan but didn't work.

`<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video.js"></script>
<body>
<video id="video_logo" width="720" height="405">
<source src="http://logo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video> 
<script>
VideoJS("video_logo").ready(function(){
    var myPlayer = this;
    var howMuchIsDownloaded = myPlayer.bufferedPercent();
    if(howMuchIsDownloaded == 1){
    myPlayer.play();  //start playing the video 
    }else{
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }
 });
 </script>
</div>
</body>`

Comment: that's not surprising at all! if you followed how to properly set up a video tag, in the documentation maybe you would have more luck .. or if you used a src for a video which was actually a video which `"http://logo.mp4" ` is definately not ... I'm not going to spooon feed you a complete code set cause your to lazy to follow good documentation, so your on your own at least until you have something that resembles how the documentation similar as the documentation

Comment: You'r wrong. The link isn't what i'm using because i don't want to share it yet. I saw the documentation and everything seems to work fine except 'var howMuchIsDownloaded = myPlayer.bufferedPercent();'. The variable howMuchIsDownloaded is always less then 1. Seems like he's not getting the buffered percent or is not buffering at all...

Comment: how long of a video is it? ... according to the doc's when the video bufferedpercent is between 0 and 1 ... but if one is never reached put in .99 instead of 1 (99% loaded)

Comment: Didn't work. I tried a different approach, use a loop and put the variable howMuchIsDownloaded into a alert to see the percentage loaded. He always return zero. do{
   var howMuchIsDownloaded = myPlayer.bufferedPercent();
   alert(howMuchIsDownloaded)
  } while (howMuchIsDownloaded<.99);
    
    alert("play")
    myPlayer.play();  //start playing the video 
    
 });

Comment: @DONSA hey so you are correct The bufferedPercent() api call does not seem to work (I am assuming a bug from new release of v4 this month). I have also attempted to use the event handle loadedalldata which does work. The problem is that it appear's video.js stops buffering data when it is a certain amount ahead of playtime. you can check out an example of that here http://ec2-23-20-36-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com/video-js.html . Why exactly do you want the whole video buffered before playing? It is a strange request after all

Comment: It's simple, I have an small animation (12 seconds) in my intro page. My first thought was export the animation to GIF but it was too big. So, I export to MP4 and insert into the page as a video without the controls, but still a litlle bit slow to load and the video constantly stops. So, i came up with this idea of play the video only after it loads. I should repor the bug to videojs? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @DONSA Didn't you already? ... i read an issue on github with same user name, ... I wrote a comment reconfirming your note. I doubt it will be a high priority fix though... If the video is only 12 seconds I'll write another update which will probably work for you.

Comment: That's me, thanks for the reconfirming. I tried your code but din't work. I put the code between <script></script> bellow the video but the code don't even run. I think the problem is in the first line '$(document).ready(function() {' because when i remove just this line, the code runs. Seems like the page doesn't load.

Comment: Hey sorry ya that first statement is jquery so include this in the head of the document `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>` also another thing i forgot to mention is that in th evideojs video tag include this `preload="auto"` which will start the video when the page loads (on browser that allow so, basically everything except iOs)

Comment: Thanks @brendan, now the code passes on the first two functions but stops after `myPlayer.on("progress", out_started);`

Comment: hmmm, this mean's that it's not registering your player.. have you replaced "my_example_video" if so could you post the error given to you in the developer console... also the browser you're using

Comment: Yes, I replaced: `_V_("video_logo_1").ready(function(){`. I think he is registering my player because when i put `myPlayer.play();` in the first or second function the video starts to play. I'm not using any developer console, I'm using Coda2 but I could try a console. Which one do you sugest? I can say when the code stops because I use `alert("text")` to know that. I'm using Chrome btw.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'`
(anonymous function)
_V_.Component._V_.Class.extend.ready video.js:21
(anonymous function)
c jquery.min.js:4
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery.min.js:4
q

Comment: @DONSA , okay I'm not able to reproduce the error (it works for me) also, I just use chrome's built dev tools (CTRL + Shift+ I) i Like it. is there somewhere I can take a look at the code live? if not I am kinda lost as to what to suggest next

Comment: Of course @brendan, there's any way i can send you a private message?

Comment: morrison.brendan1@gmail.com

Comment: Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

    morrison.brendan1@gmail.com

Comment: oops, my bad morrison.brendan17@gmail.com .. forgot a 7

Comment: @hitesh No this i will not working on safari for iOS or majority of mobile web browsers the reason being that no video is allowed to autoplay in an effort to conserve bandwidth on mobile networks (ie. a visitors data plan) as such this will not work on mobile devices and is only for desktop ... there may be a way to hack around this but I have not explored it

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether or not you want it to play only after the *page* loads, or after the video itself has finished buffering.

If you want it to play automatically upon the page loading you would want to use the  tag's ["autoplay" attribute.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp)

**Example**

```
<video controls autoplay> </video>
```

For easy to understand information on how to make some rather cool looking loading bars in CCS3, see [here](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/). CSS-tricks always has some interesting stuff.

Comment: No, i want to play only after the video itself has finished buffering.

Answer (score 1):

I have a cleaner example, also using video.js:

```
function progress(){
  video = this;
  if (video.bufferedPercent() > .95 && video.paused()) {
    video.play();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   _V_("video").ready(function(){
      this.on("progress", progress);
  });
});
```

and

```
<video src="mcd.mp4" id="video">
```